# Show e hide de elementos do form com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho um form em que 3 questões mostram uma mesma parte do formulário, e suas respostas são sim ou não, porem quando uma delas é não e as outras sim, ele esconde as perguntas do formulário que também são validas para as outras questões.

**jQuery**

```
 <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
            var $profissional = $("#decorrencia-profissional"),
                $futura = $("#decorrencia-futura"),
                $sinistroIndenizado = $("#sinistro-indenizado"),
                $possuiSinistro = $(".possui-sinistro");

            $($profissional, $futura, $sinistro).change(function() {
                if($(this).val() === "Sim") {
                    $($possuiSinistro).show(1000);
                } else if $(this).val() === "Sim" && $(this).val() === "Não"{
                    $($possuiSinistro).show(1000);
                } else{
                    $($possuiSinistro).hide(1000);
                }
            });
            $($possuiSinistro).hide(1000);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Podes mostrar um exemplo com esse comportamento que descreveste? junta o HTML e assim podemos ajudar com um exemplo a funcionar.

Comment: http://www.fbnseguros.com.br/rcsorridents/index2.php